# how to access each checkbox in Qtablewidget

Tags: python, qt

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozk9C.png)

i am trying to implement a video marging application. in this GUI video will be marged according to the order by which they are checked.if file2 is checked first then file1 then marging will happen on that order. unfortunately i can't achieve this goal.my code is as below

```
self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
j1=0
j7=1
onlyfiles3 = [f for f in listdir(desktop3) if isfile(join(desktop3, f))]
for i in onlyfiles3:
        if "info.xml" not in i:
           if "list3.txt" not in i:
               if 'output.mov' not in i:
                   self.tableWidget_3.setRowCount(j7)
                   self.cb3 = QtGui.QCheckBox()
                   self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(j1, 0, self.cb3)
                   self.cb3.stateChanged.connect(self.select_file3)
                   item3 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(i)
                   self.tableWidget_3.setItem(j1, 1, item3)
                   j7=j7+1
                   j1=j1+1
```

i am trying to list down all the files located in a specific folder. and the GUI will look like above.and my select_file3 is like below

```
    def select_file3(self):
           userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
           userhome3 = userhome + '/Desktop/Session_3/'
           userhome3 = (userhome3.replace(chr(92), '/'))
           button = QtGui.qApp.focusWidget()
           index = self.tableWidget_3.indexAt(button.pos())
```

So how to get the file name when a check box is checked and get null when checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Qt item views have built-in support for checkable items. Don't add QCheckBoxes there, but just make the QTableWidgetItems checkable.

Comment: if i have,say 3 instance of cb3,is there any way is there to access each instance separately?

Comment: Just don't do that. Filling up an item view with QCheckBoxes defeats the whole purpose of using an item view. Make the items checkable instead. The you can ask the items for their check states.

Comment: ok,Thank you.@jpnurmi.